# How does os.File implement io.Writer?

Tags: file, go, writer

I'm able to do this:

```
f, err := os.Create("file")
if err != nil {
    ....
}
by := bufio.NewWriter(f)
```

And this:

```
var _ io.Writer = &os.File{}
```

The package documentation for [os.File](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) leads to [this source file](https://golang.org/src/os/file_unix.go?s=597:624#L17) which does contain an *unexported* write function but I get an error when I try to implement an interface with an unexported function.

```
var _ Disease = &Scratch{}  // *Scratch doesn't implement Disease have spread() want Spread()
type Disease interface {
    Spread()
}
type Scratch struct {
    ....
}
func (s* Scratch) spread() {
    ....
}
```

What am I missing ?

**Update**: os.File [did need cleaning up](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16993)

Comment: Not sure what you're actually asking but `os.File` implements [Write](https://golang.org/src/os/file.go#L138)

Comment: Ah it may be a [bad link](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) because that File link goes to [file_unix.go](https://golang.org/src/os/file_unix.go?s=597:624#L17) not to file.go and I didn't look at the filename closely

Comment: Ok it's not a bad link. The File type is re-defined in multiple files under src/os but the exported methods are all in a different file. Now the question arises is how is the redefinition in the same package permitted ?

Comment: There is redefinition because only one of the files defining the type will be included in the build.

Comment: Well why don't they just stick the type declaration in the one file along with all the exported methods then ?

Comment: Because different Operating-Systems need different metadata to talk to a file (i.e. read to it, write from it, ...)

Comment: Just the type `type File struct {}` bit can move to File.go. The unexported types/methods are where the os specific work happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the exported `Write([]byte)` defined on `*os.File` here: https://golang.org/src/os/file.go?s=4417:4466#L128